# How to create transparent bottom navigation bar in flutter? tried many methods but nothing works

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have tried different methods but nothing seems working, Please help to achieve it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVhHH.png)

```
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,  //not working
```

is there any other method to achieve transparent bottom nav bar?

here is the code

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    showSelectedLabels: false,
    showUnselectedLabels: false,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,  //it is not working 
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: ('home'),
        icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.home),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: ('home'),
        icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.fileAlt),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: ('home'),
        icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.user),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: ('home'),
        icon: FaIcon(
          FontAwesomeIcons.bell,
        ),
      ),
    ],
    currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.red,

  ),
```

screenshot ..

Answer (score 0):

You can set background color of the scaffold and then set transparent background color and zero elevation to the BottomNavigationBar

```
Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    elevation: 0,
    showSelectedLabels: false,
    showUnselectedLabels: false,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: ('home'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: ('home'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
      ),
    ],
    currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
  ),
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Container()
  )
```